# Calculation of Elastic Collision with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I try to calculate elastic collision with numpy but found lost while writing the script:

```
def elasticCollisionFormular():
    while True:
        try:
            A = np.array([[m1,m2],[0.5*m1,0.5*m2]])
            B = np.array([[v1,v2],[v1**2,v2**2]])
            C = np.array([[m1,m2],[0.5*m1,0.5*m2]])
            D = np.linalg.solve(A*B,C)
        except:
            print('An error occured. Retrying...')
            continue
        else:
            return D
            break
```

The D I get is incorrect, how should arrange `D = np.linalg.solve(A*B,C)` ??

An example and its correct answers:

```
m1 = 3

m2 = 1

v1 = 4

v2 = 8

v₁' = -2 and 4

v₂' = 10 and -8
```

This is the formular by the way:
[image: this is the formular]

**Edit:**
The full code here:

```
import numpy as np

def ask_for_m1():
    while True:
        try:
            m1 = int(input('Enter the mass of object 1 :'))
        except:
            print('An error occured, please try again')
            continue
        else:
            return m1
            break

def ask_for_m2():
    while True:
        try:
            m2 = int(input('Enter the mass of object 2 :'))
        except ImportError:
            print('An error occured, please try again')
            continue
        else:
            return m2
            break

def ask_for_v1():
    while True:
        try:
            v1 = int(input('Enter the staring speed of object 1 :'))
        except:
            print('An error occured, please try again')
            continue
        else:
            return v1
            break

def ask_for_v2():
    while True:
        try:
            v2 = int(input('Enter the staring speed of object 2 :'))
        except:
            print('An error occured, please try again')
            continue
        else:
            return v2
            break

def elasticCollisionFormular():
    while True:
        try:
            A = np.array([[m1,m2],[0.5*m1,0.5*m2]])
            B = np.array([[v1,v2],[v1**2,v2**2]])
            C = np.array([[m1,m2],[0.5*m1,0.5*m2]])
            D = np.linalg.solve(A*B,C)
        except:
            print('An error occured. Retrying...')
            continue
        else:
            return D
            break


#start of program

while True:
    m1 = ask_for_m1()
    m2 = ask_for_m2()
    v1 = ask_for_v1()
    v2 = ask_for_v2()
    D = elasticCollisionFormular()
    print(D)
```

and the metrix variable(A,B,C,D) I set:
[image: here]
[image: here]

Comment: Why are you looping? What are `m1`, `m2`, `v1`, `v2`? Why is the `dtype` of your array some list with undefined elements? That code isn't even valid. Please provide an example which at least remotely looks like valid and useful code. Currently you have an infinite loop that prints `"An error occured. Retrying..."` as fast as it can.

Comment: what's `D` in your formulas?

Comment: If you are trying to do matrix multiplication with A*B, know that this is element-wise multiplication.